# Unmet dependencies installing R 3.6.2 on Ubuntu 18.14 LTS

Tags: r, ubuntu-18.04

I use 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

I wanted to upgrade my R version from 3.4.4 to 3.6.2, but now I have no R at all.

here are my actions:

1 step:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

2 step:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

3 step:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/'
```

return:

```
Hit:1 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                     
Hit:3 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                   
Hit:4 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease                
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease                      
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                      
Hit:7 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/ InRelease
Hit:8 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/ InRelease
Hit:9 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

4 step:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-base
```

return:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.6.2-1xenial) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: r-recommended (= 3.6.2-1xenial) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

then I try:

```
R --version
```

return:

```
Command 'R' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install r-base-core
```

I try:

```
 sudo apt install r-base-core


 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  r-base-core : Depends: libreadline6 (>= 6.0) but it is not 
  installable
           Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be 
  installed
           Recommends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be 
  installed
  E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I followed [these instructions](https://rtask.thinkr.fr/fr/installation-de-r-3-5-sur-ubuntu-18-04-lts-et-astuces-pour-les-packages-de-cartographie/) but sorry, they are in French.

Comment: @JackPo  You need to tell us more about your system. Installations in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS are _extremely common_ and lots of people use it for e.g. continuous integration.  (And I could point you to a number of Dockerfiles that script this.) So something makes your machine different, and we cannot what it is.  The 'libreadline6' message makes me think that maybe you are pointing at the wrong repo, you need to make sure you are matching what you have.  Lastly, there is the r-sig-debian mailing list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the etc/apt/sources.list file and realised that I had the same repository repeated. I deleted two lines and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try two things:

1. As you already appear to have installed, just to `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.  It will list candidate upgrades, you can still back out. Advantage: it resolved interdependent upgrades for you.
2. Continue what you did but list the affected packages, i.e. `sudo apt-get install r-base r-recommended r-base-hmtml`.  This will work, but may requires several iterative steps.